# Topology, sum of closed sets

Tags: sequences-and-series, general-topology

So in Engelkings book I’ve come up against this exercise:

> For given series $A_1, A_2, ...$ of subsets of topological space the following equation holds:
>
> $$ \overline{\bigcup_{i = 1}^\infty A_i} = \bigcup_{i = 1}^\infty \overline{A_i} \cup \bigcap_{i=1}^\infty \overline{\bigcup_{j = 0}^\infty A_{i + j}}$$

I don’t know how to even start this. I have the general idea, that for some infinite series if we go on and on, like the limit of it can be omitted if we just skip the second part of the sum on the right side, but still I can’t think of any purely mathematical proof.

Comment: Generally, the way to show that two sets are equal is to show that each is a subset of the other. So, you can start by assuming a point $x \in {\rm Cl} \bigcup_{i = 1}^\infty A_i$, then show that $x \in \left( \bigcup_{i = 1}^\infty {\rm Cl} A_i \right) \cup \left( \bigcap_{i = 1}^\infty {\rm Cl} \left( \bigcup_{j = 0}^\infty A_{i + j} \right) \right)$. Then the reverse direction.

Comment: @Peter Do you know about nets?  (The reason I ask is that the proof I can think of uses that as an important tool in proving one direction of the inclusion.  If you don't know about nets, then I could give a similar argument in terms of sequence limits; but then, of course, my proof would only work for the case of sequential topological spaces.)

Comment: @K.Jiang okey, proving left to right inclusion is obvious, as $ClA_i$ is containted in $Cl (\bigcup_{i=1}^\infty A_1)$ and the second thing on the right side also must be contained in the left side. The harder part is the inclusion you wrote and I ve tried proving it earlier but I failed

Comment: @DanielSchepler Unfortunetly, I’m not familiar woth nets :c. But I must read about them, because they look beautiful.

Comment: You say "sums". Did you mean "union"?

Answer (score 1):

Since you indicate that you can prove $RHS \subseteq LHS$, I will focus on the other direction $LHS \subseteq RHS$.

Thus, suppose $x \in \overline{\bigcup_{i=1}^\infty A_i}$.  In order to prove $x$ is in the union on the right hand side, I will show that $x \notin \bigcup_{i=1}^\infty \overline{A_i}$ implies $x \in \bigcap_{i=1}^\infty \overline{\bigcup_{j=0}^\infty A_{i+j}}$.  So, fix $i \ge 1$, and we want to show $x \in \overline{\bigcup_{j=0}^\infty A_{i+j}}$.  To see this, note that since the closure commutes with finite unions, we have
$$\overline{\bigcup_{i=1}^\infty A_i} = \overline{A_1} \cup \overline{A_2} \cup \cdots \cup \overline{A_{i-1}} \cup \overline{\bigcup_{j=0}^\infty A_{i+j}}.$$
However, by the assumption $x \notin \bigcup_{i=1}^\infty \overline{A_i}$, we know that $x \notin \overline{A_1} \cup \cdots \overline{A_{i-1}}$, so instead we must have $x \in \overline{\bigcup_{j=0}^\infty A_{i+j}}$.  Since we showed this is true for arbitrary $i \ge 1$, we have proved that $x \in \bigcap_{i=1}^\infty \overline{\bigcup_{j=0}^\infty A_{i+j}}$.

---

For an alternate proof of this inclusion that works in a sequential topological space, suppose we have $x \in \overline{\bigcup_{i=1}^\infty A_i}$.  Then there is some sequence $(y_n)_{n=1}^\infty$ with each $y_n \in \bigcup_{i=1}^\infty A_i$ and with limit $x$.  We now let $f(n)$ be the smallest value of $i$ such that $y_n \in A_i$.  If some finite $i$ is the value of $f(n)$ infinitely many times, then the corresponding subsequence of $y_n$ is contained in $A_i$, so $x \in \overline{A_i}$.  Otherwise, we must have $f(n) \to \infty$ as $n \to \infty$, so for any $i$ there exists $N$ such that whenever $n\ge N$, we have $f(n) \ge i$.  Thus, the subsequence starting at $n=N$ is contained in $\bigcup_{j=0}^\infty A_{i+j}$, so $x \in \overline{\bigcup_{j=0}^\infty A_{i+j}}$.  Since we showed this is true for arbitrary $i$, we thus get $x \in \bigcap_{i=1}^\infty \overline{\bigcup_{j=0}^\infty A_{i+j}}$.

More generally, using nets instead of sequences will allow this argument to work in an arbitrary topological space without much change.  (You would just need to replace "$f(n) = i$ for infinitely many $n$" with "there exists arbitrary large $\lambda \in \Lambda$ such that $f(\lambda) = i$" where $\Lambda$ is the directed set of indices for the net.)

Comment: Wow, this is amazing. Thank you so much. I wish I had seen this earlier, because this proof is beatiful. And about sequantial topology part, I haven’t learnt about it yet. I’ve just started and this excercise was in the first topic.

Answer (score 1):

As suggested in the comments, there are fancier methods of proof, but the claim can also be shown without too much difficulty using only set theory.

To simplify some notation, let $C = {\rm Cl} \bigcup_{i = 1}^\infty A_i$ and $D = \left( \bigcup_{i = 1}^\infty {\rm Cl} A_i \right) \cup \left( \bigcap_{i = 1}^\infty {\rm Cl} \bigcup_{j = 0}^\infty A_{i + j} \right)$.

Let $x \in C$. There are two possibilities we will consider. Either $x \in {\rm Cl} A_k$ for some $k \in \mathbb{Z}^+$, or not. In the former case, ${\rm Cl} A_k \subseteq \bigcup_{i = 1}^\infty {\rm Cl} A_i \subseteq D \implies x \in D$. The latter case is slightly more difficult: we proceed by induction. Let $S \subseteq \mathbb{Z}^+$ be the set of positive integers $m$ such that $x \in {\rm Cl} \bigcup_{j = 0}^\infty A_{m + j}$. The case where $m = 1$ is trivial, because ${\rm Cl} \bigcup_{j = 0}^\infty A_{1 + j} = C$, and $x \in C$ by hypothesis. So, $1 \in S$. Now suppose $m \in S \implies x \in {\rm Cl} \bigcup_{j = 0}^\infty A_{m + j}$. We have

$$\bigcup_{j = 0}^\infty A_{m + j} = A_m \cup \bigcup_{j = 0}^\infty A_{(m + 1) + j} \implies {\rm Cl} \bigcup_{j = 0}^\infty A_{m + j} = {\rm Cl} A_{m} \cup \left( {\rm Cl} \bigcup_{j = 0}^\infty A_{(m + 1) + j} \right)$$

But we have said that in this case, $x \notin {\rm Cl} A_m$ for each $m \in \mathbb{Z}^+$. Therefore, $x \in \bigcup_{j = 0}^\infty A_{(m + 1) + j}$. So, $m \in S \implies m + 1 \in S$, as desired. This shows $S = \mathbb{Z}^+$; i.e., $x \in {\rm Cl} \bigcup_{j = 0}^\infty A_{m + j}$ for every $m \in \mathbb{Z}^+$. Equivalently, $x \in \bigcap_{i = 1}^\infty {\rm Cl} \bigcup_{j = 0}^\infty A_{i + j} \subseteq D \implies x \in D$.

For the reverse inclusion, suppose $x \in D$. Either $x \in \bigcup_{i = 1}^\infty {\rm Cl} A_i$ or $x \in \bigcap_{i = 1}^\infty {\rm Cl} \bigcup_{j = 0}^\infty A_{i + j}$. In the former case, it is known that for an *arbitrary* family $\{ A_\alpha \}_{\alpha \in J}$, it is true that $\bigcup_\alpha {\rm Cl} A_\alpha \subseteq {\rm Cl} \bigcup_\alpha A_\alpha$. Applying that here, $\bigcup_{i = 1}^\infty {\rm Cl} A_i \subseteq {\rm Cl} \bigcup_{i = 1}^\infty A_i \implies x \in C$. In the latter case, $x \in {\rm Cl} \bigcup_{j = 0}^\infty A_{m + j}$ for all $m \in \mathbb{Z}^+$. Specifically, it is true for $m = 1$, in which case we have that $x \in {\rm Cl} \bigcup_{i = 1}^\infty A_i = C$, as desired.

Therefore, $C = D$, as desired.